# How can the derivative of arc length be anything except zero?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

[image]

If a and b are constants, then the above definite integral (arc length) has to be some constant.

[image]

How can the derivative of s be anything except zero (this is contradicted in the blue box)? This method of evaluation is for line integrals by the way.

Comment: Are you asking for a justification for why $\frac{ds}{dt}$ might not be $0$? Just formally, $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is "dividing off" the $dt$ term on the righthand side of the blue box..

Comment: @Tom: Yes. If you take the derivative of s with respect to t in the first image, then you should always get 0 because the derivative of a definite integral (which is a constant) is always 0.

Comment: Rather think of  $\frac d{db}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a fixed starting time $t_0$, then you may define the arc length travelled after a time $t$ and denote it by $s(t)$. This is not constant in $t$, as you travel along the curve, the travelled distance increases. So $\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}$ is the velocity at a certain time.

Comment: How can the derivative of a definite integral be non-zero?

Comment: As I explained, the $s$ your differential $\mathrm ds$ refers to is not the definite integral from the top of the page. It is an integral from $t_0$ to $t$.

Comment: Oh thanks. It's weird because I don't think the textbook actually defined what s is.

Comment: Wait. One more question. If we don't have a formal mathematical definition of $s$, then how did the textbook get $ds$?

Comment: Take $s=\int_{t_0}^t \sqrt{[f'(\tau)]^2+[g'(\tau)]^2}\,\mathrm d\tau$ as a definition. The textbook doesn't do a very good job explaining where $\mathrm ds$ comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you highlighted gives the relation between $\mathrm ds$ and $\mathrm dt$, and a nonzero relationship should exist, as you would expect a correlation between the differential and change in $t$.  In fact, it is equivalent to the integral you talked about above.

Comment: I asked the question wrong. I meant to say: if you take the derivative of s with respect to t in the first image, then you should always get 0 because the derivative of a definite integral (which is a constant) is always 0.

Comment: They never say $a$ and $b$ are constant, and rather they are arbitrary values.  It might as well be indefinite.  However, seeing as they are measuring definite lengths, there does need to be a starting and ending point, so I imagine the authors added the variables for formality.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks.